# Can I create a User Control that is just a panel that I can insert to an ASP page when a button is clicked?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am relatively new to ASP.NET so I do not know the usual practice for this kind of operation so please bear with me.

What I have at the moment Is an ASPX page that has an UpdatePanel on it with multiple Panels inside it. Every time the user clicks a button from the navigation menu (which is in another Update Panel on its own) The Panel that relates to the button is set to visible. So for every time the user clicks on of the buttons I need to hide all other panels and set that particular one to visible.

I am hoping there is a better way of achieving this as I can see it getting very messy quite quickly.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you need some like this: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Tabs/Tabs.aspx or this control: http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Accordion/Accordion.aspx

Comment: I'm already using the according for a part of the page, but the Tabs seems like a good idea. I am just worried about when the page is loaded do all the controls on every tab get created at the same time or only when the tab is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

CollapsiblePanel : http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx 
Accordion : http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Accordion/Accordion.aspx